# Browserstack multiple browser does not run for protractor

Tags: cross-browser, protractor, browserstack

I am trying to run multiple browsers in parallel using browser stack but it does not seem possible with it. This is is my config file

```
exports.config = {
  capabilities: {
    'browserstack.user' : 'abc2',
    'browserstack.key' : 'asdasdasdasdj',

    // Needed for testing localhost
    'browserstack.local' : 'false',

    multiCapabilities: [
      {
          browserName: 'Safari',
          browser_version: '8.0',
          os: 'OS X',
          os_version: 'Yosemite'
      },
      {
         browserName: 'Firefox',
         browser_version: '30.0',
         os: 'Windows',
         os_version: '7'
      },
      {
         browserName: 'iPhone',
         platform: 'MAC',
         device: 'iPhone 5S'
      }
    ]


  },
```

When i run - npm run protractor, i get this error Target browser must be a string, but is ; did you forget to call forBrowser()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify **browserName** capability under capabilities block. Below is a working sample

```
exports.config = {
  'specs': [ '../specs/single.js' ],
  'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

  'commonCapabilities': {
    'browserstack.user': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME || 'BROWSERSTACK_USERNAME',
    'browserstack.key': process.env.BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY || 'BROWSERSTACK_ACCESS_KEY',
    'build': 'protractor-browserstack',
    'name': 'parallel_test',
    'browserstack.debug': 'true',
    'browserName': 'Chrome'
  },

  'multiCapabilities': [{
    'browserName': 'Chrome'
  },{
    'browserName': 'Safari'
  },{
    'browserName': 'Firefox'
  },{
    'browserName': 'IE'
  }]
};

// Code to support common capabilities
exports.config.multiCapabilities.forEach(function(caps){
  for(var i in exports.config.commonCapabilities) caps[i] = caps[i] || exports.config.commonCapabilities[i];
});
```

The 'browserName': 'Chrome' capability will later be overriden by your multiCapabilities block.